# how to reference a static global variable that is after main function in C

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // write code here
    printf("%d\n", a);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static int a = 10;
```

how to reference a static global variable `a` in the comment position?

I know that place `a` before main will not cause this problem. I just want to know if there is any related syntax to do this?

Comment: @Jabberwocky [It causes compilation error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XmIjVwwCpuzaJ2lg).

Comment: @MikeCAT comment deleted, you can delete your comments too, thanks

Comment: Is there any reason or are you just curious?

Comment: @klutt just curious

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a *tentative definition* for `a` before `main` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int a;    // tentative definition

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // write code here
    printf("%d\n", a);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static int a = 10;   // "full" definition
```

Although if you do that, you may as well just move the full definition to that point.

Comment: This would be super confusing to read such a program. One might not be able to understand where this value of `10` came from when debugging the program.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Agreed, hence my suggestion at the end.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: This is easily remedied by adding a comment “This is a tentative declaration of a. The initial value is given in a definition below.”